# The number of way of choosing double 4 of a kind

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there is an 8-card poker game created using the standard 52 deck of cards. What is the number of way of choosing double 4 of a kind(two different ranks of cards, each with four of a kind).

1. To make 4 of kind in 5-card hands, the possible ways are  $C(13,1) \times$ $C(4,4) $$\times C(48,1) $
2. To find double 4 of a kind, I get $ C(4,4)\times\ C(13,1)\times\ C(44,2) \times\ C(13,1)\times\ C(4,4) $

Am I on the right track? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The final answer is  $ 13 \times\ 12 \times \ 946 = 147576 ?$

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly calculated the number of four of a kind five-card hands.

A double four of a kind eight-card hand is completely determined by choosing the two ranks from which the eight cards are drawn since we must choose all four cards from each of those ranks.  Hence, the number of double four of a kind eight-card hands is 
$$\binom{13}{2}$$